# How does rootviewcontroller get loaded in iOS 5

Tags: ios5, storyboard

I've just started with iOS 5 and got surprised from the beginning. Now the first thing I noticed is if I start with Single View Application there's nothing in the application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method about setting the rootviewcontroller. It just returns YES. I know, if I take a look at the storyboard I'll see an arrow pointing to the
ViewCotroller object. But how does it work if it's not coded in the .m file? Maybe it adds the code in runtime as ARC does by sending release messages dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewController that is pointed to by the "arrow" on the left that isn't attached to anything else is what gets set as the rootViewController when using storyboards.

Comment: I know, it's kind of a wizard. But what I wonder is shouldn't it be coded as well? I mean whatever you do with the help of wizards are normally reflected as bunches of codes in the background. It seems I was right about sending that message in run time.

Comment: Whatever you set in Interface Builder or Storyboard is set, just as if you has set it in code. Otherwise there would be no point to setting them using the "wizard".